# A Bi-Lipschitz application between a ball and a SSS domain

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis, reference-request, transformation

We say that $\Omega$ is a Strongly Star Shaped domain (with respect to the origin) of $\mathbb R ^n$ if :

$$\Omega  = \{x\in \mathbb R ^n : \left \| x \right \| < g(\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|})\}\cup\{0\}\; \text{and}\;\; 
 \partial \Omega  = \{x\in \mathbb R ^n : \left \| x \right \| = g(\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|})\} $$
with $g$ is a continuous, positive function on the unit sphere .

Let's assume that $\Omega $ is a Lipschitz domain (Or a $\mathcal C^1$ doamain) I want to find a **Bi-Lipschitz** application (with a **bounded Jacobian**) between $\Omega$ and the unit ball ($B$,$\left \| . \right \|_{2}$).

I tried this one$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\Phi & : & B\setminus \{0\} & \to & \Omega\setminus \{0\} \\
 & & y & \mapsto &  y\;g(\frac{y}{\left \| y \right \|}) \\
\end{array}$$
But, unluckily $\Phi$ is not Bi-Lipschitz (even if it's a bijection).

I appreciate your answers and your help.